# Unable to type class method that extends from a abstract class generic method (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, abstract-class

So I have an abstract class that implements an interface:

```js
export default interface ResponsibilityChainHandler {
  setNext(handler: ResponsibilityChainHandler): ResponsibilityChainHandler

  handle<T>(request: T): Promise<T>
}
```

```js
import ResponsibilityChainHandler from './responsibility-chain.handler.interface'

export default abstract class AbstractResponsibilityChainHandler
  implements ResponsibilityChainHandler {
  private nextHandler?: ResponsibilityChainHandler

  public setNext(handler: ResponsibilityChainHandler): ResponsibilityChainHandler {
    this.nextHandler = handler
    return this.nextHandler
  }

  public async handle<T>(request: T): Promise<T> {
    if (this.nextHandler) {
      return this.nextHandler.handle(request)
    }
    return request
  }
}
```

Now, I want to define a new class that only accepts a specific object of type `GreetingHandlerRequest` (which is defined as a class).

```js
import AbstractResponsibilityChainHandler from '../../domain/responsibility-chain.handler.abstract'
import GreetingHandlerRequest from '../../domain/greeting-handler-request.domain';

export default class WelcomeHandler extends AbstractResponsibilityChainHandler {
  public async handle<GreetingHandlerRequest>(
    request: GreetingHandlerRequest
  ): Promise<GreetingHandlerRequest> {
    return super.handle(request)
  }
}
```

However, I got the following error on the `GreetingHandlerRequest` import:

```
'GreetingHandlerRequest' is declared but its value is never read.
```

And if I try to do something inside the method like `request.existingAttr` it complains about:

```
Property 'existingAttr' does not exist on type 'GreetingHandlerRequest'.
```

But the class `GreetingHandlerRequest` has a publicly accessible attribute called `existingAttr`.

I also tried to do `import type` instead, but without success. I've been stuck for a while with this. Asking some mates and googling didn't result for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is an individual `ResponsibilityChainHandler` supposed to be able to handle a request of type `T` for *every* possible `T`?  Or is it supposed to be able to handle a request of type `T` for *one specific* `T`?  Your declarations imply the former but your `WelcomeHandler` implies the latter.  You need to pick one.

Comment: Also, for this to be a [mcve] you should give us a definition of `GreetingHandlerRequest`.

Comment: Can I get both @jcalz ? I want the `ResponsibilityChainHandler` to be generic, so I can create a chain over different types.

The `WelcomeHandler` is just a specific handler only for chains of type `GreetingHandlerRequest`.

Comment: It's not clear what the scope of "different" is when you say "a chain over different types".  Do you want *each* instance of `ResponsibilityHandler` to be able to handle different types, or do you want *different* instances to be able to handle different types?  That is, do you want a single swiss army knife or a bunch of specific tools?

Comment: I want different instances to be able to handle different types. For example, now I'm creating a chain with some handlers (including the `WelcomeHandler`) that only handle the type `GreetingHandlerRequest`.
However, I also want to be able to create a new bunch of handlers to manage also the type `Foo` and create a chain that process only `Foo` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two distinct flavors of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in TypeScript: generic *functions* and generic *types*.

---

A generic function declares its generic type parameter (or parameters) on the call signature of the function, like the `handle` method here:

```
interface RCHGenFunc {
  handle<T>(request: T): Promise<T>
}
```

The type parameter on a generic function (`T` above) isn't specified until the function is actually called, at which point the caller specifies it (or the compiler infers it on behalf of the caller).  This means that a generic function implementation must be able to deal with any possible specification of `T` that the function caller wants.

---

A generic *type* declares its generic type parameter (or parameters) on the type declaration, like the `RCHGenType` type here:

```
interface RCHGenType<T> {
  handle(request: T): Promise<T>
}
```

The type parameter on a generic type (`T` above) must be specified before you can have a value of that type.  If a generic type has a method that refers to the type parameter (as in `handle()` above), that type parameter is fixed as soon as the surrounding generic type is specified, before that method is called.  Once you are talking about, say, an `RCHGenType<GreetingHandlerRequest>`, then its `handle()` method only needs to be able to handle a `GreetingHandlerRequest`.  And so to implement that function you do not need to deal with any possible value of `T`.

---

The distinction can feel a bit fuzzy when you have a specific type with a generic method as opposed to a generic type with a specific method.  The important part is the scope of the generic.  If I take generics in the type system and make an analogy with functions in JavaScript, the difference is this (the following is JS, not necessarily TS):

```
const rchGenFunc = () => (T) => "Promise<" + T + ">";
const rchGenType = (T) => () => "Promise<" + T + ">";
```

Each of them has a parameter named `T`, but they have different scopes.  In `rchGenFunc` I don't specify `T` when I call it; instead, I call it with no parameter and then get a function back that can accept any parameter.  But in `rchGenType` I have to specify `T` when I call it, and then get back something that only works for that particular `T`.

---

Backing up to your problem: you are using a generic function but you should really be using a generic type instead.  Even in your `WelcomeHandler`, your `handle()` method is generic where `GreetingHandlerRequest` is just a coincidentally-named *type parameter*, and has nothing to do with any `GreeingHandlerRequest` interface/class you may be importing (which is why you get "unused" warnings).

So let's move the type parameter out of the call signature and up into the type:

```
interface ResponsibilityChainHandler<T> {
  setNext(handler: ResponsibilityChainHandler<T>): ResponsibilityChainHandler<T>
  handle(request: T): Promise<T>
}
```

And that means `AbstractResponsibilityChainHandler` should also be generic:

```
abstract class AbstractResponsibilityChainHandler<T>
  implements ResponsibilityChainHandler<T> {
  private nextHandler?: ResponsibilityChainHandler<T>

  public setNext(handler: ResponsibilityChainHandler<T>): ResponsibilityChainHandler<T> {
    this.nextHandler = handler
    return this.nextHandler
  }

  public async handle(request: T): Promise<T> {
    if (this.nextHandler) {
      return this.nextHandler.handle(request)
    }
    return request
  }
}
```

Finally, we can talk about `WelcomeHandler`.  Assuming that `GreetingHandlerRequest` looks like this:

```
interface GreetingHandlerRequest {
  existingAttr: string;
}
```

then `WeclomeHandler`can look like this:

```
class WelcomeHandler extends AbstractResponsibilityChainHandler<GreetingHandlerRequest> {
  public async handle(request: GreetingHandlerRequest): Promise<GreetingHandlerRequest> {
    request.existingAttr.toUpperCase();
    return super.handle(request)
  }
}
```

Here, `WelcomeHandler` is not itself a generic class.  It is a specific class that you get by extending `AbstractResponsibilityChainHandler<GreetingHandlerRequest>`, which is a specific type you get by plugging in the specific `GreetingHandlerRequest` type as the type parameter `T` in `AbstractResponsbilityChainHandler<T>`.

Now the `WelcomeHandler`'s `handle()` method accepts only `GreetingHandlerRequest` parameters.  You don't have to make it generic (there's no type parameter on its declaration), and inside the implementation you have access to the specific properties of `GreetingHandlerRequest` because of this restriction.

---

If you had said that you really do want `handle()` to be a generic method and deal with any possible request type, then we'd have had to either abandon the class hierarchy (since a `WelcomeHandler` would not properly `handle()` all requests), or we'd have to make it accept all requests but put some kind of runtime check inside so that it does nothing unless it gets the right type of request.  But that's not what you want (thank goodness) so the above solution is probably the right one for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#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-KAPzC0mJtWS6WynUKvX67OyCk0xSc7m8-mhoVCKvkmtB+vpgxKgdJ2up3sZ5tlFQeAB0SN5pZ4j0NPDnAwgHFk3GASA4C6gy+La+4zZtyhgrfbSFdUQUSVDaRNmTNTj+lvimaz+N4OZjyXFcS17KY-3-Hc9wPI8TzPVde0XTc3wyDg7G3AIoJMGDD2NNCryQa0unxThCQEcQTF3NoLxJd8bkglgeQ8Dg2g9DgfRsZo2gufwSOdV13QAdQgDAekgC8kGLKQNHdL0HXgDgE0HQMU2DC9tEoiBqOAVpaPSSxZkY4hbzbLEHygJ9FBQ-DTSQLSdL03s6LQ81v12BzWN0-T6KM7dbMyRdmMyNiOO4RcOBcABVGBYm4YRXQgSZeKzHD90PKBZDi5DXwC9Cr2IiFAmhcg4Q9DAMEcFw3UpBgcRIglQmJCchzUkd5XZFhO2LHsG0rUVq1UusQwbccBpU5NhovZtN28VC7PsL98l2PVihIu0FKdF03U9b1fUU5TJ2HEbBWbSNo1jDh4xaobpwbTqTLzAtkFAi8K37cajrak75RIky73M7ru03PtDtaqbwP6lVBsmu7BQelhgNPV7ew3Xt-N3dK4JA890aza8WFM+9H2fWaDHmj9siW-5ZygjEgPglHRoR5Q0tgpGELAhscp1Cn8qgrD-zZvCDMyAq1rxRqiWQTyaOc0WGObYKvNadjOKaH0eOI5ReDGVjenxKBZe8+X6MMagbHUKIcmoQ37KolWfLQhHhaPCoXEA6gguoFjQp9aZ6kaDZuN085CsubbhNE8SIEk6TNDkva-Ru2H1NR4yWzMxQSes0M5ryz9cncwoWYAuYAEIPGNpyGxcyw+bsKZj1cAB3Is28obhXG4QwNgAIQ9AARIRKAARSiyhkV0DY7BSxI8u933dLV8LIpiuKEs8ZKMdwposp4HmWQb8W+KKvwgA)

Comment: Thank you very much @jcalz for your detailed answer and your educational approach. You'll help more people than just me with that answer. My best wishes.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you take to answer my question. Have a good day.